# Broadcast a pyspark dataframe in spark cluster

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, broadcast

How do I broadcast a pyspark dataframe which contains 4 columns and 10 rows?

Sample Dataframe :

[image]

I tried a few options like:

1. Directly send the dataframe in `broadcast()`

Do I have to observe any constraints when broadcasting a dataframe?

`bc = sc.broadcast(df_sub)`

It throws an exception :

> py4j.Py4JException: Method **getstate**([]) does not exist

2. joining the dataframe:

`brdct = df_cate.join(broadcast(df_sub), ["commonkey"], "left")`

How do I access the broadcasted values?

Is converting the dataframe as a python `dictionary` useful? Does it affect the performance?

Comment: Please provide sample input and your expected output.

Comment: Please edit your question and write your samples in a proper way.

Comment: Please see the question .. I added the dataframe sample

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: The same dataframe should be available at the worker nodes..